# SQL State: 42X01] Syntax error: Encountered "DESC" at line 2, column 58

Tags: primary-key, derby, alter-table

I am using DBVisualiser to execute SQL commands against a Derby database. I am however having an issue with the DESC command.

I want to create a primary key with a descending sort order rather than the default ASC using the below statement

```
ALTER TABLE MESSAGE

ADD CONSTRAINT SQL130301151549641 PRIMARY KEY (SENT_TIME DESC)
```

on execution I get the following error.

> 11:49:59  [ALTER - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 0, SQL State: 42X01]  Syntax error: Encountered "DESC" at line 2, column 58. 
>   ... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]

I have played around with brackets and comma's to no avail. This may be a very simple thing to resolve.

Comment: I don't think Derby (or any other DBMS for that matter) supports a "direction" for a primary key definition. Only when creating an index you can specify a direction - although in most modern DBMS it doesn't really matter because most of them can use an index in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that `desc` is a reserved key in the `derby` database. I changed the name of the field from `desc` into `description` and rerun the spring application then it is fixed.